# useEffect() not checking a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a countdown timer with React hooks. However, my countdown timer does not properly stop at 0. I think I might be mis-using useEffect() here.

How do i get the `else` condition to fire?

And, given my implementation, which parts of React am I probably not understanding well enough?

```
 const App = () => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(5);

  // useEffect is called 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (seconds > 0){
      setInterval(() => setSeconds((oldSeconds) => oldSeconds-1 ), 1000);
    } else {
      setSeconds(0);
    }
  }, []);
return(.......)
```

Comment: Because useEffect dependency is empty array [], so inside invoke only once time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't pass any value to dependencies so `useEffect` only call once time. You can update like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;
    if (seconds > 0) {
      timeout= setTimeOut(
        () => setSeconds((oldSeconds) => oldSeconds - 1),
        1000
      );
    } else {
      setSeconds(0);
    }

    return () => {
      timeout && clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [seconds]);
```

UPDATE: If we add `seconds` in dependencies, you should use `setTimeOut` and remember clear it on `return`

Comment: every time when seconds is changed useEffect call clearInterval. No reason to use setInterval

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy  Exactly, we should use `setTimeout` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using setInterval will continuously run with the timeout you have set. If you are using useEffect i would suggest using setTimeout instead, and looking for state changes in the seconds state. Heres a working example:

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(5);

// useEffect is called
useEffect(() => {
    if (seconds > 0){
        setTimeout(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1 ), 1000);
    } else {
        setSeconds(0);
    }
}, [seconds]);

console.log(seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are 2 things going on here.

1. Once you create a `setInterval(() => setSeconds((oldSeconds) => oldSeconds-1 ), 1000)`, the condition inside will go on forever unless you do a `clearInterval` of such interval, for more see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp.
2. The dependency array on your useEffect is empty, meaning the code inside will most likely be only run once, sort of like a `componentDidMount` but not exactly like that, so in order for the check to be constantly made you should maybe set as dependency `seconds` so each time it changes, the code will run again.

If you do both things, clearing the interval (maybe on the same condition you set seconds to zero) and adding `seconds` to the dependency array should make your counter run